# Address to file offset

Tags: file-format, elf

I have read `st_value` from the ELF symbol table, with the value being 4195622. When converted to hex, the value is 400580. I am aware that the file offset is 580 bytes.

My question is how to actually convert the address to file offset concretely.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtract `0x400000` from `st_value` since the address is located in the first `LOAD` segment of the binary.

---

According to the System V ABI (generic), the meaning of the `st_value` symbol depends on what type of object file the binary is:

> Symbol table entries for different object file types have slightly different interpretations
>   for the `st_value` member.
>
> - In relocatable files, `st_value` holds alignment constraints for a symbol whose section index is `SHN_COMMON`.
> - In relocatable files, `st_value` holds a section offset for a defined symbol. That is, `st_value` is an offset from the beginning of the section that `st_shndx` identifies.
> - **In executable and shared object files, `st_value` holds a virtual address**. To make these files’ symbols more useful for the dynamic linker, the section offset (file interpretation) gives way to a virtual address (memory interpretation) for which the section number is irrelevant.

An executable ELF64 object file linked by `ld` has a canonical base address of `0x0000000000400000` given by the linker script variable `__executable_start`. This means that one can subtract the value of the base address from the `st_value` to find its file offset.

We can verify this by looking at a link map of an ELF64 binary. Here a snippet of the output of `ld -M /bin/ls`:

```
Memory Configuration

Name             Origin             Length             Attributes
*default*        0x0000000000000000 0xffffffffffffffff

Linker script and memory map

LOAD /bin/ls
                0x0000000000400000                PROVIDE (__executable_start, 0x400000)    <--------------
                0x0000000000400190                . = (0x400000 + SIZEOF_HEADERS)

.interp         0x0000000000400190       0x1c
 *(.interp)
 .interp        0x0000000000400190       0x1c /bin/ls

.note.ABI-tag   0x00000000004001ac       0x20
 .note.ABI-tag  0x00000000004001ac       0x20 /bin/ls

.note.gnu.build-id
                0x00000000004001cc       0x24
 *(.note.gnu.build-id)
 .note.gnu.build-id
                0x00000000004001cc       0x24 /bin/ls
```

This can be further verified by examining the section-to-segment mapping of the same binary via `readelf -l /bin/ls`:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x404890
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000  <-------------
                 0x0000000000019d44 0x0000000000019d44  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000019df0 0x0000000000619df0 0x0000000000619df0
                 0x0000000000000804 0x0000000000001570  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000019e08 0x0000000000619e08 0x0000000000619e08
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000000000001701c 0x000000000041701c 0x000000000041701c
                 0x000000000000072c 0x000000000000072c  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000019df0 0x0000000000619df0 0x0000000000619df0
                 0x0000000000000210 0x0000000000000210  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

The first `LOAD` segment has a base address of `0x0000000000400000`.

Compare the values in the `Off` column with those in the `Address` column:

```
$ readelf -SW /bin/ls
There are 28 section headers, starting at offset 0x1a700:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000400238 000238 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            0000000000400254 000254 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000400274 000274 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0000000000400298 000298 000068 00   A  5   0  8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000000000400300 000300 000c18 18   A  6   1  8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000400f18 000f18 000593 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          00000000004014ac 0014ac 000102 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         00000000004015b0 0015b0 000090 00   A  6   2  8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA            0000000000401640 001640 0000a8 18   A  5   0  8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA            00000000004016e8 0016e8 000a80 18   A  5  12  8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        0000000000402168 002168 00001a 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        0000000000402190 002190 000710 10  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        00000000004028a0 0028a0 00f65a 00  AX  0   0 16
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS        0000000000411efc 011efc 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000411f20 011f20 0050fc 00   A  0   0 32
  [16] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        000000000041701c 01701c 00072c 00   A  0   0  4
  [17] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        0000000000417748 017748 0025fc 00   A  0   0  8
  [18] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      0000000000619df0 019df0 000008 00  WA  0   0  8
  [19] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      0000000000619df8 019df8 000008 00  WA  0   0  8
  [20] .jcr              PROGBITS        0000000000619e00 019e00 000008 00  WA  0   0  8
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000000000619e08 019e08 0001f0 10  WA  6   0  8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000619ff8 019ff8 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS        000000000061a000 01a000 000398 08  WA  0   0  8
  [24] .data             PROGBITS        000000000061a3a0 01a3a0 000254 00  WA  0   0 32
  [25] .bss              NOBITS          000000000061a600 01a5f4 000d60 00  WA  0   0 32
  [26] .gnu_debuglink    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 01a5f4 000008 00      0   0  1
  [27] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 01a5fc 0000fe 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

Comment: @Marius.pharoe no problem - you are welcome